# Is there a way to resize the background image to fit a mobile px

Tags: css

Is there a way to resize images in order to fit screen when creating a parallax effect?
My current css:

```
.homebanner
 {
   
    background-image: url(/images/home/food3.jpg);

    /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 800px; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

 }
```

or do I have to adjust it using @media queries?

Also, I was wondering how big are CSS files usually, I've never seen one but when creating one it seems really big in term of lines.

Answer (score 3):

Setting a fixed value to a background-image will cancel the `background-size : cover;`.
If you want to get a different behaviour on mobile for example, using media queries can help, setting the background-attachment to 'scroll'.

Finally, the average file size of a css stylesheet is 50Ko, but if you think your file is too big, you can process to minify it to save some weight.

Comment: so i tried setting the background- attachment to none but nothing has changed.

Comment: My bad, it's 'scroll' instead of 'none' ;)

Comment: when i do either of those i lose the parallax effect

Comment: My first suggestion was to cancel the background-attachment (and so the parallax effect) to keep the 'background-size: cover' active. As pointed out, you can't get the property 'background-size: cover' and the 'background-attachment: fixed'. But if you want to keep it anyway you can use css medias-queries and set pixel-based sizes to match your design needs.

Comment: Oh, so id always have to adjust it based on the sizes?

Comment: If you want to keep your background fixed, yes.